# sharedpreferences not setting to null

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

The values in the sharedpreferences still exists even after using edit.clear();

I am writing a code to store a number only if sharedpreferences is null.if its not null then the dialog must not appear.

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    //Dialog to Get User Input
      if(license==null){
    AddDialog = new Dialog(License.this);
    AddDialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_fragment);
    AddDialog.setTitle("Enter a License");
    licenseadd = (EditText)AddDialog.findViewById(R.id.license);

    savebtn = (Button)AddDialog.findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
    savebtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
      @Override
      public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          license = licenseadd.getText().toString();

         SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
         //Storing Data using SharedPreferences
        edit.putString("License", license);
      edit.clear();
       edit.commit();
        AddDialog.dismiss();


      }
```

How can i fix this ?

Comment: /edit.commit(); it should be //edit.commit()?

Comment: if you comment the commit part it will do nothing, you are making a list of action to be performed and have to commit to execute them.

Comment: yes i have tried that!!..its not working..i have not commented..it came here as commented by mistake

Comment: "when committing back to the preferences, the clear() action is done first"--from comment on source code Editor.clear(). So try `edit.clear();edit.commit(); `after commit the putstring action.

Comment: I think Euporie is right. Btw, why do you want to add a string to sharedpreferences and then immediately clear it? Just doesnt make any sense to me.

Comment: because i want sharedpreferences to contain only one number

Comment: try

`edit.clear();`

`edit.putString("License", license);`

`edit.commit();`

Answer (score 0):

I have run a demo to verify that whether you put extra data to sharepreference, the clear() method is done first in the same commit. As you post

```
edit.putString("License", license);
edit.clear();
edit.commit();
```

`edit.clear()` will clear the key-value in your sharepreference, and then `edit.putString("License", license)` will add License-num in your sharepreference. So you will find the License values still exists. If you really want to add the values and then clear it, try

```
edit.putString("License", license);
edit.commit();
edit.clear();
edit.commit();
```

Hope it helps.